# UML: Can two objects of different classes have an aggregation relationship if neither of them contain's the other one?

Tags: python, uml

How is `A` related to `B` according to UML?

```py
from datetime import datetime

class B:
    def __init__(self, time) -> None:
        self.time = time

class A:
    def m(self):
        time = datetime.now()
        return B(time)
```

I'd say it classifies as an association. However im not sure if it also classies as an aggregation, since instances of `A` do not contain instances of `B` in any way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's neither. There is only a dependency from `A` to `B` (and `datetime`). `A` only produces an instance of `B` and has no remembering (association). And it is especially no aggregation whatsoever.

A composite aggregation would be, if one class has an association to another and is reponsible for its lifetime. Only one instance can hold the responsibility. Usually the semantic value of aggregation is too little to be modeled in most (though not all) cases.

As [@Christophe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3723423/christophe) noted, you could make it a `Usage` (special form of dependency which renders the same way) and add the `«Create»` stereotype. See p. 678 of UML 2.5:

> A usage dependency denoting that the client classifier creates instances of the supplier classifier.

Comment: Maybe it’s worth to add that it’s a usage dependency and that the standard «Create» stereotype could be used for more precision?

Comment: @Christophe Done. AFAIR the case of stereotypes does not matter (or so I learned from some EA conversation with Sparx).  Only they _**should** not clash with keyword names_ which is a kind of funny "information"  (p. 278).

Comment: Oh! Interesting and good to know! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @Christophe With a grain of salt... Though Sparx is part of OMG, not everything they tell is true. I don't have a reference in the specs. I'll open a question and see if someone knows details.